# Is projection of locally connected compact subset locally connected?

Tags: gn.general-topology

This question was originally at Math Stackexchange, but had no answers:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4348707/is-projection-of-locally-connected-compact-subset-locally-connected

#### Problem

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ be topological spaces, $Z = X \times Y$, $\mathcal{T}_Z$ be the product topology on $Z$, $f : Z \to X$ be defined by $f(x, y) = x$, and $C \subset Z$ be compact and locally connected.

Is $f[C]$ locally connected?

#### Background

A space $(Z, \mathcal{T}_Z)$, where $\mathcal{T}_Z$ is a topology on $Z$, is *locally connected*, if for each $z \in U \in \mathcal{T}_Z$ there exists a connected $V \in \mathcal{T}_Z$ such that $z \in V \subseteq U$.

A space is *compact* if every open cover has a finite subcover.

#### Locally connected subset whose image is not locally connected

The following shows that some restrictions are necessary for the subset $C$. Let $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$, and $Z' = \{(0, 1)\} \cup \{(1/n, 0) : n \in \mathbb{N}^{> 0}\}$. Then $Z'$ is locally connected, but not compact, and $f[Z'] = \{0\} \cup \{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}^{> 0}\}$ is not locally connected.

#### Holds when $f\restriction C$ is a quotient map

Suppose $f\restriction C$ is a quotient map. [Quotient maps preserve local connectedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426794/a-quotient-of-a-locally-connected-space-is-locally-connected). Therefore $f[C]$ is locally connected.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350112/is-restriction-of-a-projection-to-a-compact-subset-a-quotient-map) provides conditions for $f\restriction C$ being a quotient map. However, as shown there, $f\restriction C$ is not always a quotient map.

### Non-quotient strategy

There [exist maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259001/a-continuous-surjection-that-is-not-a-quotient-map) which are continuous, surjective, and preserve local connectedness, but are not quotient; in the linked example $X$ and $Y$ are both locally connected. If the claim does hold, then a general solution to this problem may need a stronger theorem for preservation of locally connectivity which includes these maps.

Comment: More generally, the provided link shows that $f \restriction C$ is a quotient map when $X$ is Hausdorff, or $C$ is closed.

Comment: No, the Hausdorffness of $X$ is insufficient, $Y$ should be Hausdorff!

Comment: In the question, the projection is onto $X$. In your answer the projection is onto $Y$. The claim is correct when projecting onto $X$.

Comment: You are right. Somehow I thought that you project on $Y$ not on $X$. Usually maps have $X$ as a domain and $Y$ as the rangle, not vice versa. But this is not so important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample to this question can be constructed as follows.

Let $X=[0,1]$ be the closed interval with the standard Euclidean topology.

Let $Y=\omega$ and $\mathcal T_Y$ be the topology on $Y$ consisting of the sets $W\subseteq Y$ satisfying two conditions:

$\bullet$ if $0\in W$, then $W=\omega$;

$\bullet$ if $1\in W$, then $\omega\setminus W$ is finite.

The definition of the topology $\mathcal T_Y$ implies that $\omega\setminus\{0,1\}$ is an open discrete subspace of $(Y,\mathcal T_Y)$.

It is easy to see that the space $(Y,\mathcal T_Y)$ is not locally connected at $1$.

Choose any sequence $(U_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of pairwise disjoint nonempty open sets in $X=[0,1]$ and let $g:X\to Y$ be the function defined by
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}n&\mbox{if $x\in U_n$ for some $n\ge 1$};\\
0&\mbox{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
The definition of the topology $\mathcal T_Y$ ensures that the function $g:X\to Y$ is continuous.

Let $C=\{(x,g(x)):x\in X\}\subseteq X\times Y$ be the graph of the function $g$. It is clear that $C$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ and hence is compact, connected and locally connected. But the projection of $C$ onto $Y$ is not locally connected.

Comment: Why is $Y$ not locally connected at $1$? Let $Y' = Y \setminus \{0\}$ and $\mathcal{T}_{Y'}$ consist of the cofinite subsets of $Y'$ and $\emptyset$. Then $\mathcal{T}_Y = \mathcal{T}_{Y'} \cup \{Y\}$ is a topology on $Y$ which satisfies your requirements. But every set in $\mathcal{T}_Y$ is connected.

Comment: @kaba $Y$ is not locally connected at $1$ because any neighborhood of $1$ is homeomorphic to a convergent sequence $\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ which is disconnected. Observe that the set $\omega\setminus\{0,1\}$ is open and discrete in $(Y,\mathcal T_Y)$.

Comment: @kaba My topology $\mathcal T_Y$ is not *a* topology, but *the* topology. It is uniquely determined by those two conditions and the subspace topology it induces on $\omega\setminus\{0\}$ is larger than the cofinite topology.

Comment: Ok. I have trouble understanding what exactly your topology $\mathcal{T}_Y$ is. How do those two conditions define a unique topology, and why does not my example topology satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean there is a maximal such topology?

Comment: @kaba Those two conditions describe neighborhoods of $0$ and $1$. All other points are isolated as singletons $\{n\}$ for $n>1$ satisfy those two conditions. Please read what is written in my answer: $\mathcal T_Y$ is *the* topology consisting of the sets (= all possible sets) satisfying those two conditions.

Comment: I see. The topology is then explicitly $\mathcal{T}_Y = \mathcal{T}_{Y'} \cup \{Y\} \cup \mathcal{P}(\omega^{\geq 2})$. This does seem to work.

Comment: Thank you very much. This may have been easy for you, but I've been agonizing with this question for a couple of weeks now! Mainly because my bets were strongly on this claim being true. It is another instance of where I should have given the other possibility more thought.